# The usage of "with" and "without"

Tags: subjects

Which one sounds natural for native English speakers among the following three sentences:

1. This door cannot be opened without removing the key from the lock.
2. This door cannot be opened without the key removed from the lock.
3. This door cannot be opened with the key inserted in the lock.

I think the first one is simplest, but I am not sure it is grammatically correct because the subject of "without" differs from the subject of the sentence.

Comment: I would use **unless**: _This door cannot be opened unless the key is inserted into the lock_. I would also ask a question like this one on [ell.se].

Comment: The door cannot be opened when the key is in the lock.   #2 Is definitely wrong.  If you want us to choose one of the three, I choose #1.

Comment: @J.R. I think that **unless** gives the opposite sense to what the OP wants.

Comment: @JavaLatte - I think you might be right....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the three, #1 sounds the most natural. "The door cannot be opened until the key is taken out." would be more clear.  The "until" implies that the key has been inserted with the intention of opening the door and that the key then needs to be removed in order for the door to open.

Comment: I would say "has been taken out", but this is probably just nitpicking :D. Either way, I second the vote for #1.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose 1.

But if you wanted to use "with", I would take out the word "inserted" i.e.,

> This door cannot be opened with the key in the lock.

Just to make it less wordy. We already assume that the key has been inserted into the lock because of the preposition "in".